# How to load TimelineJS development version instead of minimized storyjs-embed.js?

Tags: javascript, timeline

I didn't find any clue how to load the development version of storyjs-embed.js, anyone has experience on this?

Lots of files listed in https://github.com/NUKnightLab/TimelineJS and seem to included and compressed into a single file.

Tried to write to the author and yet didn't get any response...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run beautifier on that library to get formated code. For example http://jsbeautifier.org/ produced:

```
function getEmbedScriptPath(e) {
    var t = document.getElementsByTagName("script"),
        n = "",
        r = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < t.length; i++) t[i].src.match(e) && (n = t[i].src);
    n != "" && (r = "/");
    return n.split("?")[0].split("/").slice(0, -1).join("/") + r
}

function createStoryJS(e, t) {
    function g() {
        LoadLib.js(h.js, y)
    }
    ....
```

And than you can use that file for development.

Comment: Problem with this is most of the methods and var names are single/double characters which makes it hard to understand what's going on.